# how to select data frame according to index NOT in a list

Tags: python, pandas

if i have a list of number in a variable called **row**:

```
Int64Index([0, 7, 8, 9])
```

And a dataframe df. If i want to select row number using the above number. In other words, i want to select row 0,7,8 and 9.  I would do the following:

```
df.iloc[row]
```

what if i want to select those that are not in **row** variable? If i have 50 rows of data frame, and i want to skip 0,7,8 and 9, is there any shortcut to do this? I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `isin` and the `~` negation operator:

```
In [6]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':randn(10), 'b':randn(10)})
df
Out[6]:
          a         b
0 -0.498370  0.350204
1 -0.484727 -0.977876
2 -0.319675 -0.781217
3  0.618511  0.416958
4 -0.834304  1.606860
5  0.768302 -0.394504
6 -0.033161 -1.539782
7 -0.062261  1.411695
8 -0.227656 -0.527440
9  0.843263  0.927568
In [7]:

index = [0, 7, 8, 9]
df[~df.index.isin(index)]
Out[7]:
          a         b
1 -0.484727 -0.977876
2 -0.319675 -0.781217
3  0.618511  0.416958
4 -0.834304  1.606860
5  0.768302 -0.394504
6 -0.033161 -1.539782
```